# XAMPP crashes when i start Apache

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

How come when i try to start Apache from XAMPP it crashes? please leave a solution.
I believe ive installed it correctly, and MySQL runs fine, but whenever i try to start Apache, XAMPP crashes.

The error message is:

> Problem detected!
>   Port in use by "system"!
>   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port

Comment: an error message would be helpful

Comment: Kill Skype or whatever application is using port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Port in use by "system"!
>   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port

Your Apache does not crash, it simply can't start because the port it tries to bind (usually 80) is in use.

Another web server or Skype could be the reason.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/